# Using authentication with a hybrid app and Mobile Application Security

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm trying to understand how authentication is done w/ a hybrid app (and this is crucial, a HYBRID app) and the MAS service. I've enabled "Google Sign-in". But when I go to the docs, http://mbaas-gettingstarted.ng.bluemix.net/javascript#get-started-with-security, it tells you what to do when you have a token.

So - wait - how do I get the token? There is a whole part missing here. What am I supposed to do to integrate w/ Google login? Do I build that myself? And if so, am I supposed to use that token then when making requests to my services?

There does not seem to be any demo for this that uses a hybrid solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get the OAuth credentials from Google in this case. Bluemix cannot request that credential on your behalf. See here for how to do that in Google: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect

Answer (score 0):

In regards to obtaining the token from Google, you will have to use the tools provided by them to implement Google sign in. After the user signs in, you will be able to grab their specific auth token. Google provides some documentation on how to implement log in and obtain the security token here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

An example of this functionality is provided:

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log("Name: " + profile.getName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      };
```

Once you have obtained the token you can use the IBM Bluemix API to set the security token such as:

```
IBMBluemix.setSecurityToken("<token>",IBMBluemix.SecurityProvider.GOOGLE).done(function(loggedInUser){
    console.log("Valid OAuth token");
}, function(err){
    console.error("Error with token");
    console.dir(err);
});
```

This is outlined in further detail here:

http://mbaas-gettingstarted.ng.bluemix.net/hybrid#user-authentication

Comment: Both answers make sense, but can I say that this is *not* made clear in the BM docs. Further, once you set this token, how exactly do you use it then? For example, if I have a BM service setup and I want to require a valid token, how is that done?

Comment: @RaymondCamden I have edited our response. To clarify, you can get a valid token for each user that signs in, then pass that token to MAS for an extra layer of auth for each user. You can also grab user info from the valid token (prof pic, email, etc..) to customize your client side app.

Comment: I'm not getting the server aspect of this then. GIven than I set the security token, does that change calls I make to my Node app running on Bluemix? Ie, can I on that side say, "Did s/he call me with a token". If it does not, then what is the point of this? If I'm already doing my own auth and validating through Google, what does this particular API give me?

Comment: This API simply provides another layer of authentication. When you check the "Enable google sign-in" box on your MAS dashboard, you are only allowing apps with a valid Google auth token access to Mobile Data and the push service.

Comment: Ok, that's very important information. Is this documented? I suppose this sentence kind of alludes to it: "Any mobile client applications that are not in this list are denied access to the Mobile Cloud application.", but what you said was *MUCH* clearer and should be called out, don't you think?

Comment: Also, can you comment on the Node.js boilerplate code that uses ibmsecurity? It says you can use it to protect endpoints by MAS. This seems to imply that MAS can also lock down custom routes in your Node app.

Comment: @RaymondCamden can you ask a new question in regards to IBMSecurity and MAS since it is of different subject matter than the Google Auth that is being discussed here